# Covering multiple DIV / Cells with notification

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an existing bootstrap grid/table data layout as follows:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row row-striped">
  <div class="col-sm-4 result-label"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">First</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">Second</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">Third</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">Fourth</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-striped">
  <div class="col-sm-4 result-label">Description 1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">10</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">11</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">12</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">13</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-striped">
  <div class="col-sm-4 result-label">Description 2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">14</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">15</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">16</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 result-value">17</div>
</div>
```

The data is being populated with an ajax call dynamically. However, sometimes the ajax will return that there is an error with the entire row, so I want to be able to flag the error pertaining to the row by effectively putting the message over the entire data portion of the row.

For example, lets say that the "Description 2" data was wrong, then I would want the "Description 2" label to remain visible, but to place a div (or similar) over the 4 data cells that would contain an error or warning message.

At the moment, I am inserting a DIV just after the offending "col-sm-4" and that is working. However, it has two problems:

1) It covers the entire row (including the title of the row, eg: Description 2 in this case).

2) I cannot get the error DIV to fill the full height of the row itself.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to achieve what I am looking to achieve?

Thanks!

Comment: Could I see your jQuery code

Comment: @Aniket G, a bit difficult to post the jQuery, but all I am doing is inserting an element after <div "col-sm-4>, eg: <div show-error>This is the error</div> and setting the CSS for the show-error to position: absolute

Comment: I added code with the general idea, or what I assume the general idea is. Tell me if there's something you want different.

Comment: What exactly are you having issues with? The javsactipt/jquery to insert the error div? The CSS to position the error div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I changed the solution. You could use `.hide()` and `.show()` from jQuery to achieve this.

```js
$(".error-2").hide();

$(".showError").click(() => {
  $(".result-value-2").hide();
  $(".error-2").show();
  
});

$(".hideError").click(() => {
  $(".result-value-2").show();
  $(".error-2").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row row-striped">
  <div class="col-4 result-label"></div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value">First</div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value">Second</div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value">Third</div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value">Fourth</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-striped">
  <div class="col-4 result-label-1">Description 1</div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value-1">10</div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value-1">11</div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value-1">12</div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value-1">13</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-striped">
  <div class="col-4 result-label-2">Description 2</div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value-2">14</div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value-2">15</div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value-2">16</div>
  <div class="col-2 result-value-2">17</div>
  <div class="col text-center error-2">Error</div>
</div>

<button class="showError">Show Error</button>
<button class="hideError">Hide Error</button>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, I was away for a day. Thanks for the suggestion. Whereas it does work, the challenge I would have with it would be that removing the result placeholders would mean that I would have to put them back in before the next AJAX request is performed. Obviously this is not hard to do. However, it becomes a bit more complicated where the number of result columns varies......

Comment: ......In some cases, I have a pre-defined layout that has 2 result columns, in others, 3 and 4. Naturally, I could add a marker class to know how many to re-insert back in, but this feels convoluted! If it was possible to simply show / hide a div over-top of the bad cells, this feels simpler? Thoughts / ideas?

Comment: I see your problem. Since bootstrap is adaptive, there is no way to display one message in the center without remove the div's with the class of column. You could maybe change the class, but adding a div before wouldn't work. 

The only way I could think of is to either remove the div, or change the col class.

Comment: After thinking a bit more, I realized you could also use jQuery `.hide()` and `.show()`. I updated my solution above

Comment: I like that solution! Thanks a million!